# React app deployed on heroku immediately crashes code=H10

Tags: node.js, reactjs, heroku

I do have this error
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { import React from 'react';
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token import

and then it crashes
heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/"

Comment: What does your babel config look like? Seems like your `import` statements aren't being transpiled to `require`.

Comment: I dont have such file. It worked local and then when I got this error i updated node local and now I have such great error also local.   "dependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-core": "^6.0.20",
    "babel-loader": "^6.0.1",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.0.15",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.0.15",
    "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.0.15",
    "jwt-decode": "^3.1.2",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "webpack": "^1.9.6",
    "webpack-dev-middleware": "^1.2.0",
    "webpack-hot-middleware": "^2.0.0"
  },

Comment: upgrade all. still not working. it was a big mistake to use react and es5. its so unstable!!!!!! 
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.0.0",

Answer (score 0):

Solution: I got an old node on my local. And didn't sign in package.json the version, It worked local than crashed on Heroku. So i did upgrade local and finally crashed local.
What I did:
create a new application.
create-react-app hello-world

then change my index.js to

ReactDOM.render(

```
  <React.StrictMode>
    <PostRequest />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);

instead of   React.render(<PostRequest />, document.getElementById("root"));
```